# query xml string using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, linq

I have a table like this

```
Table (Id decimal,XMLContent XML)
```

now I want to query records that have specific Type
this is my Code

```
 public ActionResult Index(int? id,FormCollection frm)
    {

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        ViewBag.FormId = id;
        ViewBag.FormName = db.Forms.Find(id).Name ;
        var xMLDatas = db.XMLDatas.Include(x => x.Form).Where(x=>x.FormId==id).AsQueryable();
        foreach (string item in frm)
        {
            if (item.StartsWith("xml-") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty( Request.Form[item]))
            {
                string i = item.Replace("xml-", "");
                string value = Request.Form[item];
                xMLDatas = xMLDatas.Where(x => x.XMLContent.Contains("<" + i + "[^>]*>"+value+"</" + i + ">")).AsQueryable();
            }

        }
        return View(xMLDatas.ToList());
    }
```

but I got this error message on return

> Disallowed implicit conversion from data type xml to data type nvarchar, table 'dbo.XMLDatas', column 'XMLContent'. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: You need an XmlReader.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocumenttype?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `Contains("<" + i + "[^>]*>"+value+"</" + i + ">"))` on `XMLContent` as sql type for that column is `XML` and not `NVARCHAR`.

Basically you can call `Contains` on something that is a string or implicitly converted to string by SQL Server.

But you can try to work around it on server side. Try to load XML from the DB first:

```
var xMLDatas = db.XMLDatas.Include(x => x.Form).Where(x=>x.FormId==id).ToList();
```

Comment: I want to find xml tags for example containing <type list="true">bababa</type> that list can be true or false and the bababa is the criteria

Comment: @AbolfazlPourmohammad you can't do that not loading XMLs from databas to the server first.